# Is there any formulated relationship between the concentration of s solution and its specific heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, thermal-conductivity

I've seen in this [answer](https://socratic.org/questions/how-does-salt-change-the-specific-heat-capacity-of-water) that there is an inverse relationship between the two, as illustrated by the image below. Is there any formula describing this relationship though? Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For an ideal solution, the molar heat capacity is the molar average of the heat capacities of the pure constituents.